# How can I remove the "Microsoft Surface Type Cover Mouse" option from my Keyboard and Mouse Settings?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I recently installed Lubuntu on my Microsoft Surface. The laptop has a detachable keyboard/touchpad that is compatible with Lubuntu. There are two options in the `Keyboard and Mouse > Mouse and Touchpad > Device` dropdown menu: `Microsoft Surface Type Cover Mouse` and `Microsoft Surface Type Cover Touchpad`. Even though I enable the latter option, Lubuntu sometimes defaults to the former which is annoying and removes my ability to tap-click or right-click.

Are there any suggestions for solving this issue, such as removing the first option completely so that Lubuntu is forced to enable the second one? Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
Lubuntu Version: 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
LXQt Version: 0.17.0
```

Comment: @guiverc I went ahead an updated the post with the information you requested. I'm a new Linux/Lubuntu user so I'm unsure which information would be useful for others. Let me know if you need anything else.